# Hector : java.nio.BufferUnderflowException

Tags: java, cassandra, hector, bytebuffer

I am getting the ByteBuffer of String e.g. 100 as below

```
ByteBuffer data = IntegerSerializer.get().toByteBuffer(Integer.parseInt(data));
```

and inserting this data to column say 'MYCOLUMN'

During reading the column 'MYCOLUMN' value i am using :

```
public Objct myfunction(ByteBuffer data){
        return IntegerSerializer.get().fromByteBuffer(data);
}
```

but here i am getting following error if i mention the column 'MYCOLUMN'

```
java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at java.nio.Buffer.nextGetIndex(Buffer.java:480)
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.getInt(HeapByteBuffer.java:336)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers.IntegerSerializer.fromByteBuffer(IntegerSerializer.java:35)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very similar to [this issue](https://github.com/hector-client/hector/issues/407):

> You want to specify Int32Type not IntegerType. The latter is a misnomer and actually represents a BigInteger.